# innerHTML not working as expected

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I have searched everywhere for a solution to this problem which I cannot explain.

here is the problem, whenever I use javascript's innerHTML to inject the following string:

example:

```
var s = "<div><p><div><p></p></div></p></div>"

document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = s;
```

In Firefox, using firebug, I look at the latest markup and see `<div><p></p><div><p></p></div></div>`

Anyone know what this occurs?

Comment: You can't put a <div> inside a <p>

Answer (score 4):

You cannot nest `p` or `div` inside another `p`. Closing the `p` is how the browser attempts to make your invalid HTML valid.

Comment: Actually leaving the `<p>` unclosed is a valid HTML. The unclosed `<p>` will be closed before the next block element. It's not valid in XHTML.

Comment: But the `</p>` without an opening `<p>` is invalid HTML. Clearly the intent here is not an unclosed `<p>` but a `<p>` that contains a `div` and a `p`

Comment: Yes, `</p>` without an opening `<p>` is invalid HTML. Ignoring the last `</p>` is the browser's attempt to make an invalid HTML valid. Closing the first `<p>` is just a SGML rule.